# Synchronized method called by Android Activity onCreate method

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-activity

Is the following situation poor design or am I overlooking something important?

Here is the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity … {

  …

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     …
     buildGoogleApiClient();
  }

  /**
   * Builds a GoogleApiClient. Uses the addApi() method to request the LocationServices API.
   */
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Why is `buildGoogleApiClient` `synchronized` when it’s ever only called from inside `onCreate`?

I know it cannot hurt, but that's hardly the point of the question. What I need to know is: **Why is it necessary?**

**Edit**

source to full code: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/BasicLocationSample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/basiclocationsample/MainActivity.java

Comment: Thanks for replying. But unfortunately I don't understand your response. Thanks.

Comment: As of the method's current usage, I would say no, it's not necessary. In fact I wouldn't know why there would be multiple threads trying to build the same API client on one app.

Comment: This is from http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html. Their engineers are supposed to be topnotch, and they built android, so... it's worth wondering what is happening here.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, `synchronized` will lock the object for the duration of the call.  If there are other methods also declared `synchronized`, then only one of them will be executing at any given time.  For example, if `mGoogleApiClient` is accessed from a synchronized method on another thread, the synchronization will ensure that the other thread either sees a fully-constructed object, or a null reference.

Even with that, you can still make a case that it's a poor implementation.  A better approach would be to have each method synchronize on a private object, so that code outside the class can't inadvertently lock the object and cause unexpected behavior.  OTOH, it can be argued that `synchronized` methods are nicer for examples because there's fewer lines of code and it's plain that the synchronization applies to the entire method.

In this particular case, `volatile` might have worked, though I'm not sure how that plays out with the builder pattern.

In any event, you'd need to know more about the `...` sections of code to know if synchronization is necessary.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I added the ... to truncate the code. The source is at  https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/BasicLocationSample/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/basiclocationsample/MainActivity.javal. You seem to be explaining concurrency in general. But how does the key word apply in the provided context?

Comment: I see a few possibilities: (1) if the callbacks like `onConnectionSuspended()` can be called on an arbitrary thread, synchronization could be useful. Of course, the callbacks *aren't* synchronized, so that's not it.  (2) The synchronized method is `protected`, so perhaps the developer anticipated that it would be used in a derived class that was also multi-threaded.  (3) It got copy & pasted from some other project where it was actually necessary.  Whatever the case, if `mGoogleApiClient` is only accessed from one thread, you don't need to synchronize access to it.